Can a directory junction in a trusted folder be a trusted mount point in Windows 11?
For example, I have a home directory c:\users\me.
Inside that, I have c:\users\me\Dropbox.
I also have a junction c:\users\me\Cloud -> c:\users\me\Dropbox to indicate that my current Cloud provider is Dropbox. Stop moaning, it works for me, mostly. :)
I then configured Windows "My Documents" to refer to c:\users\me\Cloud\Documents as my Documents folder. Everything works great, except inside some applications, it says that I cannot traverse the Documents virtual folder because it refers to an "untrusted mount."
I can easily work around this by manually selecting the Dropbox virtual folder instead, but I am curious if there is any way to tell Windows 11 about this actually being trusted.
It is a junction in a trusted folder referring to another folder in the same location, but I could not figure out any way (fsutil?) to tell Windows 11 it is ok.
Please don't waste your time telling me not to do this :), I am only curious about how it is implemented and whether it can be configured.

You can try trusted site zones and add in accordingly for Intranet zone or some variation to see if that helps. Consider mapping it to the mount point using the same path or UNC if it's a mapped network drive. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/security-privacy/ie-security-zones-registry-entries

I'd try to remove the junction and replace it with a hardlink

One from designers MS Windows 2000 Mark Russinovich collected sysinternal utils and support them really. Junction tool can create, configure and delete junction directory on Windows. By Administrator rights.
Your profile have junction directory 'Documents' to 'My Documents'.
Delete junction 'Documents' and create junction 'Documents' to directory that you need by junction tool
Manual for Junction tool you can get at link junction sys tool

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
